# Can you penalize based on difference between training and testing error?

Tags: dataset, error, overfitting, algorithms, genetic-algorithms

Is it a valid or useful technique to penalize the model based on the objective function + abs(training error - testing error). The error would probably have to be scaled. This seems useful, and I am considering it for my genetic algorithm. Might this lead to overfitting somehow?